# Spring Cloud Gateway - populating trace ID in access log using Micrometer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway, micrometer

I am currently migrating a Gateway-application based on Spring Cloud Gateway from Spring boot 2.7.9 to 3.0.3. However I am having problems with populating trace ID and span ID on the Netty access log. I have created a sample application replicating my issue [here](https://github.com/pederhaag/AccessLogDemo) where I've switched from Sleuth to Micrometer.

The access log did manage to populate trace ID and span ID in Boot 2.7.9 when using spring-cloud-starter-sleuth by defining the bean below as per the [sleuth documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/integrations.html#sleuth-reactor-netty-http-server-integration).

```java
import brave.http.HttpTracing;
import reactor.netty.http.brave.ReactorNettyHttpTracing;

@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
class TraceNettyConfig {

    @Bean
    NettyServerCustomizer traceNettyServerCustomizer(ObjectProvider<HttpTracing> tracing) {
        return server -> ReactorNettyHttpTracing.create(tracing.getObject()).decorateHttpServer(server);
    }
}
```

What configuration am I missing in order for the access log to include the trace and span IDs when using Boot 3 with Micrometer?

Here is the logs the linked sample application produces where the gateway filter log includes the trace and span ID but the access log does not.

```
2023-03-01T09:01:05.018+01:00  INFO [TRACE_ID: 63ff0640986add6d1916458610155824] [SPAN_ID: 1916458610155824] 360133 --- [or-http-epoll-2] com.example.demo.MyFilter                : Filter has been hit
2023-03-01T09:01:05.911+01:00  INFO [TRACE_ID: ] [SPAN_ID: ] 360133 --- [or-http-epoll-2] reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLog      : 127.0.0.1 - - [01/Mar/2023:09:01:04 +0100] "GET /anything HTTP/1.1" 200 654 957
```

Comment: As you mentioned in the comments on my previous answer (I deleted it),  Spring Cloud Sleuth will not work with Spring Boot 3.x onwards as it has been deprecated with not work with spring-boot 3.x. you will need to find an alternative to Sleuth for distributed tracing like Zipkin, Jaeger, or OpenTelemetry.

Comment: Sleuth is for Boot 2.x, for 3.x you need to use Micrometer Tracing (the same docs you linked says this). I think I would open an issue for Spring Cloud Gateway to check if log correlation for netty access logs is possible (the data is in the MDC, it needs to be added to the access logs).